# Hadoop spawning multiple VM

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, jvm

When i start hadoop using bin/start-all.sh script, it seems to start different JVM's for name node, data node, job tracker and task tracker.

Further more, when i start a job, it seems to create another JVM for each of the job.

Is there a specific reason why hadoop does that. I understand that its necessary  in a multi node cluster environment, but it does the same even on a single node cluster.

Is there a way i can specify any config parameter that runs everything under the same JVM?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read anything that specifically says why they did it this way, but with multiple JVMs you can potentially use more of your physical RAM (depending on O/S).  You also get some isolation.  So, if you want to change how one component is configured, you only have to restart that one.  Not that that's a huge benefit, necessarily.  Also, it's probably simpler from an implementation perspective to do it the same way, and not different logic for different setups.

OTOH, why not spawn multiple JVMs?